Bipolar ADC input vs off-setting ADC input via diff amp
I am using a diff amp to feed a voltage +/- 2 V into an ADC, of which I am looking to use the ADS1258. The ADS1258 allows for either 0-5 V input or can be configured such can allow +/- 2.5V bipolar inputs.
My question is, what are the benefits of using the bipolar range of the ADC, rather than just applying an 2V offset to the REF pins on my diff amp and using the ADC at 0-5V? Its not common to see an ADC with bipolar inputs, and is the only benefit simply the fact you don't need to offset input signal?


I'm not sure I understand your (?) diagram, but you should calculate the max error both ways and compare to your error budget. BTW, if U2 is intended to drive the REF input of U1 then R5 may cause problems.
In any case, for one example, if you care about the zero, the ADS1258 (with chopping on) is guaranteed to have no more than 10uV (1uV typical) of offset with inputs shorted. To offset a 2V signal accurate to 1uV typically is not all that easy. Maybe you can measure the offset and low-pass filter it, then add it back on, but that's additional computation and another input. And you still have potential errors from the subtraction.

Understood. I thought this would be the case as its just calculating overall error budget. The drawing is from the EVAL board where is shows and example off offsetting the output.
In regards to the ADC itself, if we assume our references / offsets are perfect with zero error, is there any difference between measuring 0-5 V (with an offset) vs +/- 2.5V bipolar inputs, other than the increased computation and associated errors. Does one method provide better accuracy than the other or is it exactly the same in regards to ADC performance?

If the offsets are perfectly accurate, perfectly stable and perfectly noise-free, then I don't think there is any difference except for nulling where linearity comes into play etc. When it comes to the null, 1uV is sub-ppm performance, so unlikely to be achievable affordably.
